# Incrementing FOR loop for each line in a text file (batch)

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, text

Ok, before I state my problem, let me provide you with some background:

I am creating a messaging service for my friends and I to message each other at school.  How it works is basically each user starts the .bat file I put on their computer.  Then, two windows open: one that has an input which reads "Text:" and another which is really another file which is displaying a text file that is updated once a second.  When the user inputs text, it is concatenated to the text file.  This is what that part looks like:

```
:message 
if %a%==1 (
echo %computername% has joined the chatroom at %time%! >> %place%chatroom.chatfile
set a=0
)
cls
echo.
echo.
set /p text="Text: "
if "%text%"=="quit" goto quit
if "%text%"=="clear" goto clear
if "%text%"=="restart" goto startup
goto tidyup
:send
echo %computername% at %time%: %text% >>%place%chatroom.chatfile
goto message
```

And the updating text file part:

```
:window
cls
type %place%chatroom.chatfile
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > nul
goto window
```

As I moved along, I realized if the text file is more than 20 lines or so, then you couldn't see the bottom part.  I tried the `more`command to solve this, but this annoyingly scrolls down so that you can't actually read anything.

After that, I found a pretty good solution: Store a separate file called history.txt and move the first line of the main text file to this one on the condition of the original text file's number of lines being greater than 20.

Again, I encountered another problem: This only removes *one* line from the text file.  Let's say the original text file is 25 lines long.  How would I move these lines?

This is what I have so far:

```
:tidyup
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > nul
set file=%place%chatroom.chatfile
set /a cnt=0
for /f %%a in ('type "%file%"^|find "" /v /c') do set /a cnt=%%a
set /p firstline=<%file%
if %cnt% GTR 20 (
set /a cnt2=%cnt%-20
for /l %%g in (1, 1, %cnt%) do (
echo %firstline%>>%place%history.chatfile  ::pay attention to this line
)
for /f "skip=%cnt% delims=*" %%a in (%place%chatroom.chatfile) do (
echo %%a >>%place%chatroom2.chatfile    
)
xcopy %place%chatroom2.chatfile %place%chatroom.chatfile /y >nul
del %place%chatroom2.chatfile /f /q)
goto send
```

The line where I placed `::pay attention to this line` is where I need this question answered:

How do I increment the `for` loop so it moves %cnt% amount of lines from the original text file to history.chatfile

OR

Is there a much simpler way to accomplish what I am doing?  I.e. A "cut" command in batch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "file=q27350263.txt"
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
:: read lines from file into variables "$1..$asmanylinesasthereare"
SET /a cnt=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "%file%"') do (
 set /a cnt+=1
 CALL SET $%%cnt%%=%%a
)
SET /a cnthist=cnt-20
SET /a cntlive=cnthist+1
IF %cnt% gtr 20 (
 DEL "%file%"
 FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,%cnthist%) DO CALL >>"%file%.history" ECHO(%%$%%a%%
 FOR /l %%a IN (%cntlive%,1,%cnt%) DO >>"%file%" CALL ECHO(%%$%%a%%
)


GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q27350263.txt` containing some data for my testing. All you'd need do is change the filenames to suit yourself.

Essentially, what this does is to load the contents of your chatfile `q27350263.txt` into variables $1..$25 (or whatever) then since we are aware of the count of lines (in `cnt`) we can determine which lines land up in the history file ($1..$(cnt-20)) and which go back into the chat file ($(cnt-20+1)..$cnt).

The `call echo` syntax allows you to access the value of the variable as it changes. In the first instance, batch parses `CALL SET $%%cnt%%=%%a` and executes `set $%cnt%=value from line` so `$thecurrentvalueofcnt` receives the text from the current line.

In the second pair of instances, %%a contains a number so the `call echo`'s target is `%$1%` (where 1 is the value of `%%a`)

Note that the redirector can be placed either side of the `call`

Comment: Thank you so much!  I only needed to make a few minor adjustments to make it fit my program.