# Execute a series of commands when a batch program is closed

Tags: batch-file, command, exit

So, I am continuing to revise the program I described in my previous question [Incrementing FOR loop for each line in a text file (batch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350263/incrementing-for-loop-for-each-line-in-a-text-file-batch).

As I am moving along, I am attempting to create a portion which will only grant access to a text document while the program is running.  To do this, I am granting access on start up with `net use`.  However, my dilemma is that I do not know of any event handler in batch that could make my program run `net use /delete` (<= I know the syntax is incorrect; besides the point) whenever the user closes the window (as in, literally click the red "X").

What event, or any command in batch, would allow me to do this?

Edit: I found something about the `/wait` command but I have no idea how this would help me with running the `net use /delete` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `net use`, you could use `pushd` with a UNC path to create a temporary network drive mapping.  For example:

```
pushd \\localhost\c$\Users\%username%\Documents
```

Then, regardless of whether you `popd`, `endlocal`, `exit /b`, or the user terminates the script with the red X, the temporary mapping will be deleted at the end in any case.

Just make sure you `setlocal` at the top of your script, or at least somewhere before you `pushd`.  It's generally good practice to put `setlocal` at the top of every script immediately after `@echo off` anyway, unless you have a specific reason not to.

---

If you need to authenticate, then use a combination of `net use` and `pushd`.  Use `net use` without a drive letter, then `pushd \\UNC\path && net use \\computername /delete`.  Here's a more complete example:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "remotePC=minastirith"
set "user=%remotePC%\adminUser"
set "pass=Password"

:: establish an authenticated session
net use \\%remotePC% /user:%user% %pass%

:: pushd and immediately terminate the net use
pushd \\%remotePC%\share && net use \\%remotePC% /delete

:: The next two commands demonstrate that even though
:: the session has been disconnected, pushd still has
:: temporary access.
cd
dir

pause

:: When you popd, endlocal, exit /b, or close the window,
:: there's no longer an authenticated session.  Another
:: attempt to pushd should result in an error.
popd
pushd \\%remotePC%\share

pause
```

Comment: I should have been more specific.  I need access to the \\localhost, so is there a way to temporarily grant access via the pushd command?  I.e. an equivalent of /USER:username password in net use for pushd?

Comment: I didn't understand what \\localhost did when I left the comment.  I specifically mean \\(another_computer_name)

Comment: @RecentWebDev2000 I added an additional example demonstrating how to combine `net use` with `pushd` to provide temporary authentication.  See the edits above.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!  I poked around a bit more and came to the conclusion that this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add a second batch. Won't help for the user clicking close button (you need to write a real program for that).

Batch1

```
Net use etc
Call Batch2
Net Use/delete etc
```

Batch2

```
Your commands
```

When batch two is terminated the rest ofthe commands in Batch1 runs. You need to read help `call /?`.